# How to print list of directories and files and exclude names of directories?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write out a list of directories in a given folder. Here is the code I'm using:

```
 Dir.glob("**/*").each do |fname|
        puts "<file href=\"#{fname}\" />"
 end
```

Here is the output:

```
<file href="css" />
<file href="css/site.css" />
<file href="css/specific-tweaks.css" />
<file href="css/videojs.css" />
```

I want to exclude the directory name. Expected output:

```
 <file href="css/site.css" />
 <file href="css/specific-tweaks.css" />
 <file href="css/videojs.css" />
```

Comment: Be careful using `**/*` to find files. If that gets run against a big directory hierarchy, it can result in your code stopping as it builds the list of files and stores that list in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check if it's a file.

```
Dir.glob("**/*").each do |fname|
  puts "<file href=\"#{fname}\" />" if File.file?(fname)
end
```

Comment: This worked very well. Thanks for teaching me something new!  I will mark as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at using `Find.find` over Dir. It's a bit more efficient and scalable.

The example from [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) shows what you need:

> The Find module supports the top-down traversal of a set of file paths.
>
> For example, to total the size of all files under your home directory, ignoring anything in a “dot” directory (e.g. $HOME/.ssh):

```
require 'find'

total_size = 0

Find.find(ENV["HOME"]) do |path|
  if FileTest.directory?(path)
    if File.basename(path)[0] == ?.
      Find.prune       # Don't look any further into this directory.
    else
      next
    end
  else
    total_size += FileTest.size(path)
  end
end
```